# React/Typescript: Idiomatic code for custom components that merge attributes?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, typescript

Versions: Typescript 2.3, React 16, Bootstrap 4.

I have a solution that sort of works, outlined below, that involves importing another external library to get this done.  I feel like there must be a standard solution to merge the attributes for a custom component, but using the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package is the only way I've come up with.

Writing a custom `AppButton` component for my app, I want to have a default style, but allow overriding.

First version looked like:

```
export interface AppButtonProps 
extends ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>{
}
export class AppButton 
extends React.PureComponent<AppButtonProps, object> {
  render(){
    return <button 
      {...this.props}
      className="btn btn-primary" 
    />;
  }
}
```

Used with code like this, to override the color of the button:

```
<AppButton type="submit" className="btn-success">Do the thing</AppButton>
```

But that doesn't work, depending on the order of the `<button>` attributes, you either get a button that's `btn btn-primary` or `btn-success` - but what I want is `btn btn-success`.

My current approach uses the [classnames](https://www.npmjs.com/package/classnames) package:

```
export class AppButton
extends React.PureComponent<AppButtonProps, object> {
  render(){
    return <button 
      {...this.props}
      className={classNames("btn", "btn-primary", this.props.className)} 
    />;
  }
}
```

This only *sort-of* works, it results in `btn btn-primary btn-success`, which isn't quite what I want in terms of the merging the attributes, but it displays correctly in this specific case - I guess because Bootstrap is preferring `btn-success` over `btn-primary`.

The only obvious solution I can see to get the exact styles I require would be to parse and scan the incoming `props.style` attribute for `btn-*` and only add `btn-primary` if not present.

So, the question: Is there a built-in utility in one of of Typescript, React or Bootstrap that solves this problem? Or maybe I want some other package?

Or perhaps this is actually the wrong approach and I should be writing my own custom properties in `AppButtonProps` and writing a bunch of style logic?

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest about using [`defaultProps`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#defaultprops) to use `btn-primary` as a default class if no other value is provided:

```
export interface AppButtonProps 
extends ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>{
}
export class AppButton 
extends React.PureComponent<AppButtonProps, object> {
  static defaultProps = {
    className: "btn-primary",
  };
  render(){
    return <button 
      {...this.props}
      className={classNames("btn", this.props.className)} 
    />;
  }
}
```

Based on your comments below, you could also add a separate prop for the class that determines the button's main appearance:

```
export interface AppButtonProps 
extends ButtonHTMLAttributes<HTMLButtonElement>{
  mainButtonClass?: string;
}
export class AppButton 
extends React.PureComponent<AppButtonProps, object> {
  static defaultProps = {
    mainButtonClass: "btn-primary",
  };
  render(){
    return <button 
      {...this.props}
      className={classNames("btn", this.props.mainButtonClass, this.props.className)} 
    />;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou - good idea.  That worked for making the output be exactly `btn btn-sucess`. But, still uses `classnames` package - is this really how people are creating custom components?  (Will mark your answer as correct if nobody suggests a better approach)

Comment: No, wait - this is worse.  If I try to add any custom style to the button, like width or something, the btn-primary won't get applied.

Comment: If that's the behavior you want, there's no way to get around parsing the value of `className` or add a new prop. I edited my answer to do the new prop solution.